# Sample the solution space of an inequality system $A x \leq b$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, convex-optimization

Given the following inequality system:

$A x \leq b, A \in \Re^{m \times n}$

I would like to sample the solution space. My first approach to solve this problem was by brute force, e.g. randomly generate $k$ solutions and test whether they satisfy the system, but as the system gets larger this process takes time. **Do you know of any existing algorithm that can sample the solution space efficiently?**

Comment: The solution space is infinite, so you can't have a uniform distribution. So what probability distribution are you going to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that your polytope is bounded and that you want to sample uniformly from the polytope.

There are Markov Chain Monte Carlo sampling methods for this problem.  In particular, an algorithm called "Hit-and-Run" is widely used. See this survey paper by Santosh Vempala:

https://www.cc.gatech.edu/~vempala/papers/survey.pdf

Comment: Thank you. Randomized techniques seem to work well and I think that my problem is also bounded. Do you know if the problem can be solved deterministically when the dimensionality increases e.g. find the vertices of the polytope and interpolate (convex property)?

Comment: As I understand it, the problem is NP-hard, so an efficient scheme is not expected to exist (and would imply P=NP.)